# Is it possible to change the logger settings of PhantomJS

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I am using PhantomJS with Selenium WebDriver in Java. One thing I find annoying is the initial PhantomJS bootstrap logs. It was quite useful to see them in the beginning, but soon enough they just look messy on my screen. So, is it possible to control the logging settings of PhantomJS in my case?

Thank you very much.